# Symfony 4 save button to submit request keep reloading the current page

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

Actually there's no request sent as if the function isnt even executed

it already shows in the logs that it uses POST/SponsorNew and doesn't load "SponsorListPage"
after submitting save it in the database

besides i applied the same code on another entity from the same project and it worked

```
//Add method
    /**
     * @Route("/sponsorNew",name="newSponsorPage")
     */
    public function newSponsor(Request $req):Response{
        //1.Create form view
        $sponsor= new Sponsor();
        //1.b prepare the form
        $form= $this->createForm(SponsorType::class, $sponsor);
        //2. Handel http request sent by the user
        $form=$form->handleRequest($req);
        //2.b check the form
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            //3.Persist data
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($sponsor);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute("SponsorListPage");
        }
//1.c render the form
        return $this->render('sponsor/new.html.twig',[
            'f'=>$form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

and here is the Form

```
class SponsorType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('numContact')
            ->add('type')
            ->add('sponsor_save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Sponsor::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

here is the template to fill the blanks

```
<div class="container">
     <h1>Add new Sponsor</h1>
     {{ form_start(f) }}
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>
        Name of the Sponsor
      </label>
      {{ form_widget(f.nom,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>
       Email of Sponsor
      </label>
      {{ form_widget(f.email,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>
       Contact Number
      </label>
      {{ form_widget(f.numContact,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>
      Type
     </label>
     {{ form_widget(f.type,{'attr':{'class':'form-control'}}) }}
     </div>
     {{ form_widget(f.sponsor_save,{'attr':{'class':'btn btn-sm btn-success'}}) }}
     {{ form_end(f) }}
</div>
```

Comment: You're not rendering any form errors, are you sure the form you're submitting is valid?

Comment: it was a constraint on numContact that prevent submitting the form..it worked after deleting it..it was the form_errors that made me observe the problem thank you!